# Iniciando el int main ()

Tags: c++

Buenas noches, tengo una duda respecto a esta inicialización del main(), nos lo dió así nuestro profesor de esta materia. Alguno me puede explicar para que sirve ? Los temas que estamos viendo son archivos (binarios y texto) y enlaces con nodos

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    for (int i=1; i < argc; i++){
    cout << argv[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Me da la sensación que tienes varios conceptos entendidos mal o que no sabes expresarlos bien.

> Esta inicialización del main()

La función `main` no se inicializa. La función `main` es el punto de entrada de la aplicación, como función puede ser declarada y definida. La inicialización es algo reservado a objetos y variables, no a funciones.

> Alguno me puede explicar para que sirve ?

El código que muestras es tan sencillo que debería ser auto explicativo, te lo resumo:

```
    for (int i=1; i < argc; i++){
    cout << argv[i] << endl;
}
```

Es un bucle `for` que define una variable de tipo entero (`int`) y nombre `i` que obtiene como valor inicial `1` (`int i=1`) y que va a aumentar su valor de uno en uno (`i++`) hasta ser estrictamente menor que la variable `argc` (`i < argc`) que se ha recibido como parámetro de `main`.

En el cuerpo del bucle, se encadenan dos operadores de desplazamiento de bits `<<` sobre el objeto `cout` aplicados sobre el puntero `argv` (recibido como parámetro) que está siendo indexado mediante la variable `i` (`argv[i]`) y sobre el objeto `endl`.

#### Documentación.

- [La función `main`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).
- [Bucle `for`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for).
- [Tipos fundamentales](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) (como `int`).
- [Inicialización de variables](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).
- [Operadores de incremento/decremento](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) (`++`).
- [Salida a consola](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) (`cout`).
- [Operador de inyección](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) (sobrecarga del operador de desplazamiento de bits `<<`).
- [Carácter de final de línea](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) (`endl`).

#### Errores.

El código que has compartido no compila.

- Carece de la inclusión [`<iostream>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream).
- Usas objetos del [espacio de nombres](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) `std` sin una cláusula [`using`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace).
- La función `main` no tiene retorno (aunque esto no impide que compile).
- Falta la llave de cierre de la función `main`.

#### Consejo.

Repasa los conceptos básicos de C++.